Asymptotic distribution involving a high-dimensional matrix
Let $ \varepsilon \sim \mathcal{N}({\bf 0}, I_n)$ be a n-dimensional multivariate normal RV and $x_1,x_2,...,x_n \sim \mathcal{N}({\bf 0}, I_p)$ be i.i.d p-dimensional multivariate normal RVs. $X$ is a $n\times n$ random matrix where the element in row i and column j is $x_i^Tx_j$/p. Find the distribution of $\varepsilon^TX\varepsilon$/ $\sqrt{n}$  when n and p converge to infinity. I note that, by LLN, X converges to $I_n$ given fixed n when p converges to infinity then the problem becomes simple. But i'm not sure if it's true when n and p converge to infinity simutaneously.

I think the first question you need to answer is in which sense you want to consider the object of interest and its distribution when the dimensions are infinite. (Perhaps in the free probability framework?) If you let $Y=(x_1|\cdots|x_n)\in\Bbb R^{p\times n}$ then $X=Y^TY/p$ is a (normalized) $n\times n$ Wishart matrix. The empirical distribution of its eigen values is known to follow a Marchenko−Pastur distribution, the spectral measure of a free Poisson variable.

@nejimban Thanks for the information about Marchenko−Pastur distribution. Actually I'm doing a hypothesis test where the num of features p>> sample sizes n and  X  is a pivot quantity i constructed under H0. $x_i$ is not necessarily normal . I just consider the simplest case first. I'm not familiar with the free probability framework. It seems to be a complex problem. Am i in the wrong way?
